# Is there a (somewhat high level) C++ library to create pdf documents that runs on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, c++, ios, pdf-generation

I need a C++ library that runs on Android and iOS which can be used to create PDF documents.

So far I have found [libHaru](http://libharu.org/):

> libHaru is a free, cross platform, open source library for generating PDF files.

The library seems fine and I already found a working [example](https://github.com/bygreencn/iPhonePDF) on how to use it with iOS.

But I would like to have a library less "low level", because in libHaru you have to manually create new pages, line breaks etc. So the question is if someone can advice me any C++ library which can run on Android and iOS and is a little bit more high level.

As a bonus: It would be great, if that library is also free (as in freedom) or at least free to use.

Edit: I have tried Qt and it is rather clumsy to use in such an early development stage (regarding iOS and Android development). I would appreciate a stable library with good documentation provided.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Qt for that. The class you would be looking for is [`QPdfWriter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpdfwriter.html) The nice thing about it is, that as you draw onto that thingy, you can replace the `QPdfWriter` with different kinds of `QPaintDevices`, like `QWidget` or `QImage` and so forth. It's very generic and high level, but Qt is also quite big.

Comment: Thanks, I am to going to give this a try even though I do not like the idea of using Qt for just this one functionality (because as you already stated it is BIG). I will accept this answer if nobody offers a library with less overhead.

Comment: I am removing my acceptance for this answer (keeping the upvote), because Qt is not working for me. You have to recreate the XCode project everytime you change some Qt settings (you could add all the Qt frameworks and dependencies manually). And the printing support does not seem to work correctly for iOS. I enabled printing support by removing `QT_NO_PRINTING` define and adding `printsupport` to my projects .pro file but it is still not recognizing `QTextDocument::print(QPagedPaintDevice*)`. LBNL: There is no decent documentation for using Qt with iOS and Android (it is still beta stage).

Comment: Oh and yeah I could use `QPdfWriter` with a `QPainter` instead of `QTextDocument` with a `QPrinter`, but that is not very nice for text document creation. And the `QPainter` crashes as soon as I am trying to paint something in it (I was able to create a blank PDF, nothing more).